# if condition within groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-manipulation

Calculate the `target` column where default value is `1` but it is `0` when a group within ID1 has a `Yes` so for example in `9` there is one value as `Yes` we want to keep other `No` as `0`

 Given target col is expected answer

```
ID1 ID2 Match target
4   A10 Yes   1
4   A20 No    0
5   A30 Yes   1
6   A50 No    1
6   A60 No    1
7   A70 Yes   1
8   A60 No    1
9   A30 Yes   1
9   A20 No    0
9   A10 No    0
```

Comment: There is a little ambiguity in question. So, essentially are you trying to map every yes to 1 and No to 0? is the target column given the one you are expecting?

Comment: Yes the given target column is the expected answer. "No" is 1, in case of 6 in ID1 column because there is no "Yes" for 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for compare with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) for test groups with only `No` value:

```
m1 = df['Match'].eq('No').groupby(df['ID1']).transform('all')
#or test not equal Yes
m1 = df['Match'].ne('Yes').groupby(df['ID1']).transform('all')
#alternative
#m1 = ~df['ID1'].isin(df.loc[df['Match'].ne('No'), 'ID1'])
m2 = df['Match'].eq('Yes')

df['target1'] = (m1 | m2).view('i1')
print (df)
   ID1  ID2 Match  target  target1
0    4  A10   Yes       1        1
1    4  A20    No       0        0
2    5  A30   Yes       1        1
3    6  A50    No       1        1
4    6  A60    No       1        1
5    7  A70   Yes       1        1
6    8  A60    No       1        1
7    9  A30   Yes       1        1
8    9  A20    No       0        0
9    9  A10    No       0        0
```